# Biot-Savart's law in magnetic medium

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have read that in a medium, $B$ changes but $H$ does not. So does this mean that in the expression for biot-savart's law $\mu_0$ can be replaced by $\mu$? I tried to look for biot-savart's law in medium, but could not find anywhere. Everywhere $\mu_0$ is used.
Is my guess correct?

Comment: > *"B changes but H does not"* -- in what sense? Changes when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your medium is isotropic, homogeneous, time independent, and fills all space then yes it would be valid. Note that if the last assumption falls (which is most often the case), you can have problems due to boundary conditions at the interface. Physically, you can have surface currents at the boundary, giving rise to additional magnetic fields. These boundary effects can be neglected if your medium filled region is large enough so that you can be sufficiently far from the boundaries in a restricted region inside it.

Note that you have similar problems for dielectric materials with induced charges at its surface. Check out Griffith's *Introduction to Electromagnetism* for more information.

Hope this helps and tell me if something's not clear.